# Continued Power Function Message

Tags: c, pow

I keep getting the error message that my I have an undefined reference to the power function, but I'm not really sure where that is occurring or why my code is coming up with that error because I have used to power function before in this way. If anyone could help me figure out why it isn't working now I would really appreciate it.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h" //Needed for strlen()
#include "math.h"

#define MAX_BITS 32
#define MAX_LENGTH 49
#define NUMBER_TWO 2
#define NUMBER_ONE 1
#define TERMINATOR '\0'

//Code to find the index of where the string ends
int last_index_of(char in_str[], char ch) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; i++) {
                if(in_str[i] == ch) {
                        last_index_of == i;
                }
        }
        return last_index_of;
}

//Code to find the start of the fractional aspect
void sub_string(char in_str[], char out_str[], int start, int end){
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 1) {
                out_str[i] = in_str[start] + in_str[end-1];
                i++;
        }
}

int main()
{
        //Declaration of variable
        char input[MAX_LENGTH +1]; // +1 for '\0'
        int number;
        double exponent;
        char output[MAX_BITS];
        int fraction;

 sub_string(input, output, 0, TERMINATOR);

        //Input from the user
        printf("Enter a floating point value in binary: ");
        scanf("%s", input);

        //Calculates the Decimal Part
        for (int i = 0; i < last_index_of(input, TERMINATOR) ; i++) {
                number = number + number + input[i];
        }
        printf("%d", number);

        exponent = -1;
        //Calculates the Fractional Part
        for (int j = 0; j < last_index_of(input, TERMINATOR); j++) {
                if (j == last_index_of) {
                        fraction = NUMBER_ONE/(pow(NUMBER_TWO, exponent));
                        printf("%d/n", fraction);
                }
                else {
                        fraction = NUMBER_ONE/(pow(NUMBER_TWO, exponent));
                        printf("%d + ", fraction);
                        exponent--;
                }
        }

        return 0;

}
```

Comment: Did you try to add `-lm` option to your linker?

Comment: Although not a requirement, it is good style to use `#include <header.h>` for library headers, rather than `#include "header.h"`. The latter will work too, but should only be used for user-defined headers.

Comment: You are calling `sub_string` with `end == '\0'` and in the function you are using `in_str[end-1]`, which is out of bounds.

Comment: Besides the problems mention in the answer from purplepsycho notice that `if (j == last_index_of) {` is also a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Some problems:

- you need `-lm` option to linker to tell it where to find `pow` function
- `last_index_of` is not correctly written, you use the function name as an internal variable, you can correct it this way:

  ```
  //Code to find the index of where the string ends
  int last_index_of(char in_str[], char ch) {
      int ret = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; i++) {
          if(in_str[i] == ch) {
              ret = i;
          }
      }
      return ret;
  }
  ```

  Note that you can replace your `last_index_of()` function by `strlen()`
- as pointed in comment, `sub_string()` is not functionnal. A corrected version could be:

  ```
  //Code to find the start of the fractional aspect
  void sub_string(char in_str[], char out_str[], int start, int end){
      int i = 0;
      while (start != end) {
          /* warning, bounds are still not tested...*/
          out_str[i++] = in_str[start++];            
      }
      out_str[i] = '\0'
  }
  ```
- Instead of calling `last_index_of()` in your exist `for` loop condition, you should take its value to re-use it:

  ```
  for (int j = 0; j < last_index_of(input, TERMINATOR); j++) {
      /* Error here: will never be TRUE */
      if (j == last_index_of) {
          /* ... */   
      }
      else {
          /* ... */   
      }
  }
  ```

  would become:

  ```
  int last_index = last_index_of(input, TERMINATOR);
  for (int j = 0; j < last_index; j++) {
      if (j == last_index) {
          /* ... */   
      }
      else {
          /* ... */   
      }
  }
  ```
- Another problem, you use `number` variable without initializing it, you should write `int number = 0` instead of `int number;`

---

After that, there is also a problem with your logic.

You have some idea of what you want to do, but it is not clear in your code.

It seems that you want

- the user to input some string in the form `10010.100111`
- to split this string into two parts `10010` and `100111`
- to convert the first part into integer part `10010` -> `18`
- to convert the second part into fractional part `100111` -> `0.609...`

This decomposition may lead you to write this kind of code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

#define MAX_BITS 32
#define MAX_LENGTH 49

//Code to find the index of where the string ends
int last_index_of(char in_str[], char ch)
{
    int ret = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; i++) {
        if (in_str[i] == ch) {
            ret = i;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

void sub_string(char in_str[], char out_str[], int start, int end)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (start != end) {
        /* warning, bounds are still not tested... */
        out_str[i++] = in_str[start++];
    }
    out_str[i] = '\0';
}

void split(char *input, char *first, char *second)
{
    int idx = last_index_of(input, '.');

    sub_string(input, first, 0, idx);

    sub_string(input, second, idx + 1, strlen(input));

}

int main()
{
    //Declaration of variable
    char input[MAX_LENGTH + 1]; // +1 for '\0'
    char first[MAX_BITS];
    char second[MAX_BITS];

    /* Input from the user */
    printf("Enter a floating point value in binary: ");
    scanf("%s", input);

    /* split integer and fractionnal parts */
    split(input, first, second);

    /* decode integer part */
    printf("integer part:\n");
    for (int i = strlen(first) - 1, j = 1; i > -1; --i, j <<= 1) {
        if (first[i] == '1') {
            printf("%d ", j);
        }
    }

    /* decode frac part */
    printf("\nfractionnal part:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(second); ++i) {
        if (second[i] == '1') {
            printf("1/%d ", 2 << i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have made the changes that you suggested, but now when I use my code I am not getting the desired output. When I enter 1101.1011101 I want to get 13 + 1/2 +1/8 +1/16 +1/32, but I am getting 327651/0 + 1/0 +1/0 +1/0 +. Any ideas why I am getting such a different output?

Comment: When I run the code above. The answer I get is a Segmentation Fault (core dumped). Not sure why that is occurring or even what it is?